# Notepad++ Doc Switcher Styling?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ I use the Doc Switcher as well as document tabs. Is there any other way to style the Doc switcher area? I'd like to make the background the same color as my main window background. I searched for themes in Google but it doesn't look like it's possible to style this area.

Comment: You may have more chances at the official NPP site : http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ or sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/

Comment: I don't know of any way. I would guess it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check **Notepad 6.6.8.** (or higher). [Its release notes](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.6.8-release.html) claim the following:

```
Better theme support: all internal docking dialogs apply selected theme
background / foreground colour.
```

Answer (score 1):

**This older answer applies to N++ prior to version 6.6.8.**

I have checked N++ source code and then I realized I should verify with all other tool windows.
Please see the Notepad++ with multiple tool windows displayed:

[image]

I can say that **selected style affects only the editor area. No tool windows are affected by selected style.** This is also backed by fact that in **Style configurator** you set only colors of language elements. No window elements (selected item, disabled item, etc.) are included.